# Grab Latest Data Based on String

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table with Forecast, Budget, & Actuals. I need to grab the latest data based on the month which is prefixed in the d_period field (Ex: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.). The query should  always default to the latest month (no relation to current month - the upload varies so it could be 2 months ago, 4 months ago, or 1 month in the future). I just always need to grab data for the highest month of the year

[image]

From the below table I would just need to extract the data associated with Aug since this is the highest month. The table will only have current years data so don't need to worry about duplicated months spanning various years.

---

I'm not sure what the right approach is achieve this. I assume this needs to be `SPLIT` but not sure how to then grab the max month. Do I need to create a staging table with the month mappings and then use a MAXBY() possibly? i.e. {(Jan, 1), (Feb, 2).... etc.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution. I did it in *MySql* using [str_to_date](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions) because it has the same date functions as *Presto*.

p.s
[Presto was rebranded as Trino in December of 2020.](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)

```
select  d_period
       ,spend
from 
       (
        select t.*
              ,dense_rank() over (order by month(str_to_date(substring(d_period,1,3), '%b')) desc) as rnk
        from   t
        ) t
where   rnk = 1
```

| d_period | spend |
| --- | --- |
| Aug - Forcast | 10000 |
| Aug - Actuals | 9992 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfa2e2646176fffe53e1f883f68a02c2&hide=1)

Comment: I have never used `DENSE_RANK()` before - I will be reading into that function tomorrow to better understand how this solution works! This is working great though, TYSM!

Comment: The reason I'm using `dense_rank` is so you could easily choose the last month (rnk=1),  last two months (rnk<=2), last three months (rnk<=3)etc. For what you asked `rank` would work just fine.

Comment: Yea rank is perfect since I eventually will need to do that for other insights!

Comment: Didn't know it was rebranded! At our company it's still called Presto (not just in conversation, the links and tools we use to query all have Presto branding). Good to know for future questions though - will tag both!